# How to reshape only last dimensions in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, reshape

Suppose I have `A` of shape `(...,96)` and want to reshape it into `(...,32,3)` keeping both lengths and number of preceding dimensions, if ever, intact.

How to do this?

If I write

```
np.reshape(A, (-1, 32, 2))
```

it will flatten all preceding dimensions into one single, which I don't want.

Comment: This use of `-1` isn't an ellipsis.  It is shorthand for 'calculate the one (unambiguous) dimension that retains the same overall size'.

Comment: Did the posted solution work for you?

Comment: @Divakar absolutely, thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way would be to compute the new shape tuple using the shape info concatenated with the new split axes lengths and then reshaping -

```
A.reshape(A.shape[:-1] + (32,3))
```

Sample runs -

```
In [898]: A = np.random.rand(5,96)

In [899]: A.reshape(A.shape[:-1] + (32,3)).shape
Out[899]: (5, 32, 3)

In [900]: A = np.random.rand(10,11,5,96)

In [901]: A.reshape(A.shape[:-1] + (32,3)).shape
Out[901]: (10, 11, 5, 32, 3)
```

Even works for `1D` array -

```
In [902]: A = np.random.rand(96)

In [903]: A.reshape(A.shape[:-1] + (32,3)).shape
Out[903]: (32, 3)
```

Works because the leading axes for concatenation was empty, thus using the split axes lengths only there -

```
In [904]: A.shape[:-1]
Out[904]: ()

In [905]: A.shape[:-1] + (32,3)
Out[905]: (32, 3)
```

Comment: If anyone uses this in Tensorflow: make sure to manually convert any "None" dimensions in A.shape to "-1" before reshaping.