# How do I flatten a np array by one dimension only?

Tags: python, numpy

I have an numpy array

```
array([[[1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6]],

       [[1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6]]])
```

and i want

```
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
```

How do I do that?

Comment: `a.reshape(-1,a.shape[-1])`?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46183967/how-to-reshape-only-last-dimensions-in-numpy help? Alternately: are you familiar with `.reshape`? What is the shape of the example input? What is the shape of the example output? Can you see what the rule is, that tells you how they are related?

Comment: One array has (2,2,3) shape, the other (4,3). Read `np.reshape` docs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to flatten only some dimensions of a numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18757742/how-to-flatten-only-some-dimensions-of-a-numpy-array)

Answer (score 2):

ypu want convert 3d array to 2d array.
so do this for any 3d array you want:

```
sh = 3d_array.shape

2d_array = 3d_array.reshape(sh[0]*sh[1], sh[2])
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The general formula to flatten a given axis would be:

```py
def flatten_axis(arr, axis):
    """The flatten axis is merged with the axis on its right.
    Such that `res.shape[axis] == (arr.shape[axis] * arr.shape[axis+1])`"""
    if not 0 <= axis <= arr.ndim - 2:
        raise ValueError(
            "Expected `axis` to be between 0 and "
            f"{(arr.ndim-2)=}, but found {axis=}"
        )
    shape = arr.shape
    new_shape = tuple([*shape[:axis], -1, *shape[axis + 2 :]])
    return arr.reshape(new_shape)
```

Which acts as follows:

```py
arr = np.random.randn(3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 15)

print(f"               {arr.shape = }")
for axis in range(arr.ndim - 1):
    print(f"{axis = }  -->  ", end="")
    res = flatten_axis(arr, axis=axis)
    print(f"{res.shape = }")
    assert res.shape[axis] == arr.shape[axis] * arr.shape[axis + 1]
```

Results:

```
               arr.shape = (3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 15)
axis = 0  -->  res.shape = (15, 7, 11, 13, 15)
axis = 1  -->  res.shape = (3, 35, 11, 13, 15)
axis = 2  -->  res.shape = (3, 5, 77, 13, 15)
axis = 3  -->  res.shape = (3, 5, 7, 143, 15)
axis = 4  -->  res.shape = (3, 5, 7, 11, 195)
axis = 5  -->  ValueError: Expected `axis` to be between 0 and (arr.ndim-2)=4, but found axis=5
```

Answer (score 0):

Reshape will do. Read this https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html

```
array=np.array([[[1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6]],

   [[1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6]]])

array.reshape(-1,array.shape[2])
```